# What is the WPF equivalent of displaying an Image on a Canvas using ImageData in Java SWT

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

What is the WPF equivalent of the following Java SWT code?  I want to create an Image from a list of RGBA values and display on a Canvas.

```
private Image GetImage()
{

    ImageData imageData = new ImageData(imageWidth, imageHeight,32,palette);

    int pixelVecLoc=0;
    for (int h = 0; h<imageHeight && (pixelVecLoc < currentImagePixelVec.size()); h++)
    {
        for (int w = 0; w<imageWidth && (pixelVecLoc < currentImagePixelVec.size()); w++)
        {
            int p = 0;
            Pixel pixel = currentImagePixelVec.get(pixelVecLoc);
            p = (pixel.Alpha<<24) | (pixel.Red<<16) | (pixel.Green<<8) | pixel.Blue;                
            imageData.setPixel(w, h, p);            
            pixelVecLoc++;
        }
    }

    imageData = imageData.scaledTo(imageScaleWidth, imageScaleHeight);
    Image image = ImageDescriptor.createFromImageData(imageData).createImage();
    return image;   
}
```

Then draw it on a Canvas:

```
gc.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Use an Image control and assign a `WriteableBitmap` to its `Source` property. Or use one of the `BitmapSource.Create()` overloads to create a BitmapSource from raw pixel data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a short snippet showing how you can create a custom RGBA buffer and write pixel data to it ([based on this example](http://interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2006/03/10/wpfrawpixels)):

```c#
int width = 512;
int height = 256;
int stride = width * 4 + (width % 4);
int pixelWidth = 4;  // RGBA (BGRA)
byte[] imageData = new byte[width * stride];       // raw byte buffer

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    int yPos = y * stride;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        int xPos = yPos + x * pixelWidth;

        imageData[xPos + 2] = (byte) (RedValue);   // replace *Value with source data
        imageData[xPos + 1] = (byte) (GreenValue);
        imageData[xPos    ] = (byte) (BlueValue);
        imageData[xPos + 3] = (byte) (AlphaValue);
    }
}
```

Then use the [`BitmapSource.Create Method (Int32, Int32, Double, Double, PixelFormat, BitmapPalette, IntPtr, Int32, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616046(v=vs.110).aspx) method together with a [PixelFormats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pixelformats(v=vs.110).aspx):

```c#
BitmapSource bmp = 
  BitmapSource.Create(
    width, 
    height, 
    96,                    // Horizontal DPI
    96,                    // Vertical DPI
    PixelFormats.Bgra32,   // 32-bit BGRA
    null,                  // no palette
    imageData,             // byte buffer
    imageData.Length,      // buffer size
    stride);               // stride
```

Note that the byte-order is reverse except the alpha component (BGRA) as shown in the snippet.

To transfer the result to canvas you can first create an [`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx), set the **BitmapSource** as `Source` and finally add that to the canvas:

```
// create image and set image as source
Image BmpImg = New Image();
BmpImg.Width = width;
BmpImg.Height = height;
BmpImg.Source = bmp;

// add image to canvas
canvas.Children.Add(BmpImg);

Canvas.SetLeft(BmpImg, 0);  // to set position (x,y)
Canvas.SetTop(BmpImg, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for that - how would you display that on a Canvas?

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy I added an example. Disclaimer: my VS is down at the moment so I could not double-check. I go from memory. (anyone) let me know if something is wrong and I'll update.